Can not run python script outside of visual studio 2022, works fine inside visual studio
When i run the Python script outside visual studio 2022 the black prompt immidiately closes again but when i run it inside visual studio it works as intended.
So far i am just trying to create a interface where you can choose to perform actions by selecting with your arrow keys.
I have tried running the script thru cmd and with both python 3.10 and 3.7.
from turtle import clearscreen
import keyboard
import time
import os
import colorconsole
import sys



i = 0
def clear():
    os.system("cls")

def menue():
    if i == 0:
        print(" >", end="")
    print("bootloader programming")
    if i == 1:
        print(" >", end="")
    print("system controller programming")
    if i == 2:
        print(" >", end="")
    print("options")

menue()

while True:
    def bootloader():
        print("what bootloader do you require?")

    def systemController():
        print("what unit do you wish to program?")
    if keyboard.is_pressed('down'):
        i = i + 1
        if i == 3:
            i = 0
        clear()
        menue()
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('up'):
        i = i - 1
        if i == -1:
            i = 2
        clear()
        menue()
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('enter'):
        if i == 0:
            bootloader()
        if i == 1:
            systemController()
        if i == 2:
            options()

    time.sleep(0.1)


    def comConf():
        print("input desired COM-port and press enter")
        comDesire = input()

    def lockedConf():
        passwordInput = input("password:")
        if passwordInput == "supersecretpassword":
            print("welcome admin person")

    def options():
        i2 = 0

        def optionsMenue():
            if i2 == 0:
                print(" >", end="")
            print("back")
            if i2 == 1:
                print(" >", end="")
            print("select COM-port")
            if i2 == 2:
                print(" >", end="")
            print("locked config")

        optionsMenue()
        time.sleep(1)
        while True:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('down'):
                i2 = i2 + 1
                if i2 == 3:
                    i2 = 0
                clear()
                optionsMenue()
            elif keyboard.is_pressed('up'):
                i2 = i2 - 1
                if i2 == -1:
                    i2 = 2
                clear()
                optionsMenue()
            if keyboard.is_pressed('enter'):
                if i2 == 0:
                    clear()
                    menue()
                    break
                if i2 == 1:
                    comConf()
                if i2 == 2:
                    lockedConf()
            time.sleep(0.1)


"the black prompt"?

please excuse my inability to use correct terminology:) the terminal window that you normally get when starting a basic script.

I wouldn't say you normally "get" a terminal when you start a basic script. I would say you open a terminal and then start your script. The terminal should neither appear nor disappear. This is what is strange about your statement - because its the terminal, its just there when you start the script, and still there when the script runs, and still there when the script finishes. I Unless you are doing something like "launching" this script? I think I need to know how you start the script ... b/c really you should be able to start at a terminal and type python myscript.py ...

Okay i have gotten a little smarter today. If i launch the script by entering cmd and navigating to the folder were my script is located, i can launch it by entering "python myscript.py". Altough in my testing i later discovered that if i added a line "input()" before the first "i = 0" i was able to launch the script by double clicking it right in the folder but as soon as i gave it an input it closed.

okay we probably need to see your script. It is entirely possible the program ends and then the terminal closes which is normal (when you "launch" the script by double-clicking it, which is kind of Windows thing). In VSCode it is completely different - when a program ends, the IDE (VSCode itself) doesn't close.

Try using the python IDLE. Search it in your search bar if on windows.
